# experimentalism into uncharted sonic landscapes

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Perhaps there is nothing more to the album than its case that experimentalism into uncharted sonic landscapes did not (i) ______ with Stockhausen. Or perhaps its forays— many of which could rightly be dubbed sophomoric— into the avant-garde also lead to the (ii) _______ :that to create an unprecedented sound one has to (iii) _______ a discernible melody.

(i)  (A) come full circle   (B) culminate **(C) die**

(ii) **(D) unsettling conclusion**  (E) unwarranted hypothesis (F) uncharacteristic rebuttal

(iii) (G) choose to create **(H) forgo producing** (I) subtly embed

The above question I found in a test. Answers to the blanks were given (C, D, H). I am okay with the answers to the first and third blanks. But, having trouble to understand the second blank. Can anyone explain why the answers to the blank was given option D, not E?

Comment: [Corrections: Or perhaps his forays.///I'm having trouble **understanding** the second blank.]

Answer (score 1):

Answer (E), "**unwarranted hypothesis**" doesn't fit for two reasons:

1. If the cited evidence actually **led** to a hypothesis, then it wouldn't be **unwarranted**.
2. It makes more sense to say that the evidence leads to a **conclusion** than to a hypothesis, unless there is some examination of a hypothesis that follows.

Comment: If the evidence leads to a conclusion then how can it be unsettling?

Comment: @Richard  Suppose I find evidence in the form of symptoms that leads me to the conclusion that I am infected with coronavirus. Won't that unsettle me? That is, won't it trouble me?